# Android studio pop up menu disappearing quick

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Even after checking this :

[image]

and having these settings :

[image]

When i mouse hover a method i do get that quick doc popup but it disappears after a while making it impossible to read the docs before it disappears. I tried removing my hand off the mouse to make sure it doesnt move -still disappears, I tried tapping on the popup window but this doesnt seem to help, i also tried to reach for the right top pin button but i can never get there before it disappears.

How to make it stay so i can read the docs?

Oh and if i disconnect my device than this phenomenon stops, it seems to me that it has something to do with logcat that requests focus when it has updates...

Answer (score 0):

If I keep the default parameters and just check the `autopopup` checkbox, I get a popup that only get dismissed when I move my cursor out of the function name.
So you might want to get back to the default config if something makes the popup disappear by itself.

However, usually I personally prefer to use the keyboard shortcut :
put the | or mouse cursor on the function definition or call you want to get a doc for.
Hit `F1` (on mac, can vary with the OS)
You get a documentation box that only get dismissed when you click outside of hit or tap a key.